# Pythonic way to write calculate function for a calculator - Python

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am creating a text calculator that does not work completely conventionally. It works like this:

- **Operation Input:** The user inputs the operation the calculator will process (`+` for addition, `-` for subtraction, `*` for multiplication, or `/` for division)
- **Operand Input:** The user inputs in each operand of the calculation, pressing Return between operands. Once the user has inputted all of his desired operands, striking Return three times initiates calculation.

**Calculation:**

When a user enters in *more than two operands*, instead of doing:

`operand1 plus/minus/times/divided by operand2`,

It does:

`operand1 plus/minus/times/divided by operand2 plus/minus/times/divided by operand3`,

And so on for all of the inputted operands.

The code for this simply loops through the list of inputted operands, `operandList`, and uses the chosen operation, `operation` (and `result` is the result of the calculation):

```
def Calculate():
    global operation, operandList, result
    operateCount = 0
    result = 0
    while operateCount < len(operandList):
        if operation == '+':
            result += operandList[operateCount]
        elif operation == '-':
            result -= operandList[operateCount]
        elif operation == '*':
            result *= operandList[operateCount]
        elif operation == '/':
            result /= operandList[operateCount]        
        operateCount += 1

    if operation == '+':
        resultName = 'Sum'    
    elif operation == '-':
        resultName = 'Difference'
    elif operation == '*':
        resultName = 'Product'
    elif operation == '/':
        resultName = 'Quotient'

    if result.is_integer():
        print(int(result), '=', resultName)
    else:
        print(result, '=', resultName)
    print()
```

This is super inefficient because it checks for the operation twice, and once inside the while loop, which is even worse.

Obviously if I write one of those while loop blocks for each operation and begin each one with an if statement to check for the operation that is much worse.

If I did that you would see that the only difference between each block of code is the operation sign in `result +,-,*,/= operandList[operateCount]`.

How can I:

- Cut out the redundant code that checks for the operation and executes the respective loop, and
- Reduce/ change the redundant code that checks for the operation when it displays the `result`?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Please ask for specifications if necessary. And if you down vote, please comment your reason for doing so so I can make changes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key idea is, build a `dict`:

```
import operator

ops = {
    '+': (operator.add, 'Sum', 0),
    '-': (operator.sub, 'Difference', 0),
    '*': (operator.mul, 'Product', 1),
    '/': (operator.truediv, 'Quotient', 1),
}
```

I'm associating to each operator symbols **three** items: the function to use, the name to use, **and** (which you seem to have ignored!) the "neutral" starting point.  Starting always at `0` as you do makes products and quotient risible -- multiply and divide by whatever, it doesn't matter, if it starts at `0`, it **stays** at `0` forever, you know!-)

Now things get simpler...:

```
def Calculate():
    global result
    op, resultName, result = ops[operation]
    for item in operandList:
        result = op(result, item)
    if result == int(result):
        print(int(result), '=', resultName)
    else:
        print(result, '=', resultName)
    print()
```

I have **no** idea why you're so inordinately fond of `global` and messing with indexing without necessity.  `is_number` apparently is a method only of `float`s and you're initializing `result` to an `int`, so it could crash the code -- I've replaced it with a sensible check.

No need for `global` for names you're only using and **not** assigning -- and of course it would make sense to lose the `global result` and instead `return result` at the end; but I've left it in just in case there might be any sane reason to have it global (I can't think of any).

But the core idea is: in Python, for dispatching purposes, **think `dict`** first and foremost!

Added: OP asks peculiar questions in comments, such as "What exactly is the function of the import statement?" -- answer, obviously, is "to make another module available" (in this case, module `operator` from Python's standard library, to get its functions performing addition, multiplication, and so forth).  Also "what is the 'neutral starting point'" -- answer, obviously, is "the initial value of `result` before you start adding, multiplying and so on.

In the OP's original code in the Q, `result` was unconditionally initialized to zero.  If you start with zero and multiply it by whatever number(s), it **stays** zero -- it's not a "neutral" starting point for a series of multiplication, it's more of a "fixed" point, a "black hole" in a sense.  So, I used different initial values depending on the operation.

Comment: What exactly is the function of the import statement? What is the function/ purpose of the `operator` part in `operator.xxx,`? This is a class? For what?

Comment: "[D]efinitely not from Python"?  How long have you been away? ;-)  ([is_integer docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer))

Comment: I'm still confused. Could you answer my questions please?

Comment: @Jacob, you asked two questions starting "How can I" and I answered them: **use a `dict`**, and **use a `dict`**.  **That** is how you "Cut out the redundant code that checks for the operation and executes the respective loop", **and** that is **also** how you "Reduce/ change the redundant code that checks for the operation when it displays the result", which are the two questions you asked.  Since I **did** answer your questions, I find this comment asking me to do so simply absurd.

Comment: I now understand that add, sub, mul, and truediv are methods of an operation class

Comment: Yes, you have answered my questions. However, I am asking for follow-up answers to explain your answer because I simply do not understand it.

Comment: @Jacob, `operator` is a **module**, not a **class** (not that it makes much difference).  Maybe what confuses you is that I **also** fixed the terrible bug you had, whereby `'*'` and `'/'` would **always** give a `result` of `0` no matter what the `operandList` -- you didn't **ask** to fix your bug, you didn't even **remark** on it -- I just can't stand bugs in code and I squash them whether asked to do so, or not.

Comment: @DSM, tx for the pointer -- another bug (`AttributeError`) if `result` is `int` (and it **is** initialized to `int`).  I'd better edit to point this out.

Comment: @Jacob, I didn't see any follow-up question to which I could possibly offer follow-up answers.  My code speaks for itself.  StackOverflow is scolding me for this long discussion in comments and I definitely don't want to go to chat.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Okay, I see. add, sub, mul, and truediv are functions in module operator. Thanks for fixing the bug. Could you show me the contents of the add, sub, mul, and truediv functions?

Comment: Yeah, because of the precision issues involved I always prefer to use `fractions` anyway, although the module isn't very popular for some reason.  Not sure why.

Comment: @AlexMartelli How come you can't provide follow-up answers to my simple, related follow-up questions? If I can't get an answer I can fully understand, I cannot accept your response. Please engage in chat with me.

Comment: @Jacob, module `operator` is coded in C -- see file `Modules/_operator.c` in the Python sources for "the contents of" each of its functions.  Or, read the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=operator#operator.add &c.

Comment: @Jacob, I've already spent FAR more time engaging in this pointless "extended discussions in comments", and answering **every** pointless question you asked, than I should have.  I'm off to more rewarding endeavors.

Comment: @AlexMartelli Ah, okay. I thought `operator` was a custom module you created. This clears some of my confusion up.

Comment: @AlexMartelli If it is pointless to you, it's simple - don't bother responding.

Comment: @Jacob, the **answer** got upvotes so obviously it wasn't pointless: it's proving helpful to **some** readers.  As for ignoring this unproductive follow-up, it's StackOverflow's fault for alerting me with a red number every time somebody addresses me, with no way to filter out this particular Q, or some particular poster, as far as I know.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I did not say your answer was pointless. I understand your answer is useful to some readers; however, I do not understand it myself because of my lesser knowledge.

Comment: @Jacob Hit me up if you still need explanation of any of this. I'm not as knowledgeable as Alex Martelli, but I know enough, and being a recent noob myself I have a little bit more patience.

Comment: @RickTeachey Ah, now I see how this works. Very clean and efficient.